# Linked Excel pivot tables not showing data for calculated field in Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have several pivot tables in an Excel file, linked to queries in a MS Access database. I have added a calculated field in an Access query to include as a filter for the pivot tables. However in the linked Excel pivot table, the filter shows "All" or "" as entries just for this calculated field. I have refreshed, saved, and closed both the Access and Excel files.

Calculated field in Access:

```
Year Check: IIf([Record Number] Like "8?16T*",2016,"")
```

(Made to double check the year certain records have been added.)

My coding/expression building is probably rough and cumbersome but I just wanted it to result in either 2016 or blank. Which it does in Access, but in the Excel pivot tables there is no "2016" or "blanks" option for the filter drop down menu.